# Install Vendor failed using php composer.phar install via SSH

Tags: php, ssh, openssl, composer-php, symfony-3.4

I want to install Vendor from composer.json and composer.lock files Via SSH using

**php composer.phar install**:

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 43 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download doctrine/lexer from dist: 
The "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/lexer/zipball/83893c552fd2045dd78aef794c31e694c37c0b8c" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Cloning 83893c552f...
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Have you tried looking up the given error using Google?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, I found it: It was OVH Configuration (file : .ovhconfig) by replacing : container.image to stable : (container.image=stable)

Answer (score 0):

It is an OVH Configuration (file : .ovhconfig) by replacing : container.image to stable : (container.image=stable)